# Enforcing Code Formatting Rules In Collaborative Java Development

Tags: java, eclipse, mercurial, code-formatting, policy

We are a small team of developers working on a common Java/Maven project. We are using different versions of Eclipse, a common Mercurial repository (on Bitbucket) and three different operating systems. Since each developer has his/her personal preferences, we all use different coding styles and code formattings ("else" on the same line/on a different as the previous closing bracket, or using at most 80/100/120 charactes per line because some of use have bigger screens than others, etc.). As a result, when code is commited to the repository, it sometimes appears that there have been changes to a class, even though only the formatting was changed. This makes the real changes hard to trace.

So we were discussing solutions, and probably the best would be, if we would agree on a project standard and from now on, every code in the repo has to comply to this standard. If a collegue checks out code from the repo, a tool would convert it into his/her favourite format and just before committing it is converted back to the repo standard.

I was wondering if there is a tool for formatting code, that

- could be run on any operating system
- could be easily and extensively configured (such as the Eclipse formatter)
- would allow for configurations to be shared
- AND could be run, without the developer noticing that it is there.
- OPTIONALLY could be run also from the console or as a separate task (eg. from maven)
- OPTIONALLY is free

The point about automation is very important: I should easily integrate and ideally not bother the developer by forcing him/her to run a special script or press an extra button on each commit.

**What I have done so far**:

I added the following line to my .hgrc to create a hook.

```
[hooks]
precommit = python:.hg/perform_code_formatting.py:perform
```

and created a file called perform_code_formatting.py

```
import re,os,sys,mercurial

def perform(repo, **kwargs):
   from subprocess import call
   call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Of course, `call` will eventually replaced by a code formatting tool. But this approach is already flawed, because I am not sure what tool there is, that will run on any operating system and fulfill all the requirements mentioned above.

**Tools**

- beautyj: runs on java, but not enough configuration options
- indent/astyle: powerful tools, however, OS dependent
- Jindent: not free
- eclipse formatter: so far the best option. Could also be run from the console. However, since everybody has a different installation directory, some initial effort has to be made and the script/mercurial configuration has to be done on each working station individually.

**My questions**

Is there a tool, that fulfills all the requirements I listed? Does anybody have any experience with this "different formatting issue" and has come up with solutions / workflows / policies to deal with it?

Thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jalopy, an open source tool for code formatting. Probably your team can try this.

http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I looked at Jalopy, but the last commit was 9 years ago, and all the download links are dead by now. I also had a look at the fork, Jalopy2, but the documentation is practically non-existent, and when you try to check it out from github, "mvn install" produces a .jar, with no manifest attached.

Comment: Looks like you need to put your hands into it for your own needs